# Counting the number of times an action have been performed

Tags: python, function, loops, counter

this is a sample code to count the number of times the `len(set_forbidden) > 0`. Now, if it counts the condition greater than 3, then i have to call `openthedoor(uppumanga)` and then reset the count back to zero. But when i try to print the `count`, i am getting count = 1, any help to solve this will be appreciated.

```
count = 0
def rydbergset(value,count):
if len(set_forbidden) > 0:
    count+=1
    last_time = True
    print "this is the count greater than three-"+ str(count)
    if (last_time == True) and (count>3):
        openthedoor(uppumanga)
        count = 0
    else:
        last_time = False
return set_forbidden,count
```

Comment: You need the word `and` for a logical and in Python... `&` is for bitwise and...

Comment: @JonClements It was a mistake! Now also the count is not getting updated. So it is not calling  `openthedoor(uppumanga)`

Comment: Take a step back and look at your code again... You've got last_time and last_time_ (with an underscore)... We've also no idea where/what `set_forbidden` or `uppumanga` are coming from either...

Comment: There may be an error in the loop. You should expand the code.

Comment: @JonClements I am just showing a small portion of the relevant code i asked.

Comment: What is the point of `last_time`? you always set it to `True` before checking its value.

Answer (score 0):

`count == 0`  **does not** assign `0` to the `count` variable,
`count = 0` will do the job

Please also make sure that you are assigning the output `count` to your global `count`

`(set_forbiden, count) = rydbergset(value, count)`

Comment: I updated the code, now also the count is not getting updated!

Comment: @mudaliyar Please check my latest edit. Make sure that you are assigning output count to your global one!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, if I understand the question correctly

```
count = 0
def rydbergset(set_forbidden, count):
    if len(set_forbidden) > 0:
        count+=1
        if (last_time == True) and (count>3):
            last_time = True  # Only relevant after you pass the check.
            print "this is the count greater than three-"+ str(count) # Only relevant after you pass the check.
            openthedoor(uppumanga)
            count = 0
        else:
            last_time = False
    return set_forbidden,count
```